# Safari background: url

Tags: css, safari

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно записать код

```css
background:url("../image/strelka.png") no-repeat scroll 97.5% 50% / 12% 32% transparent;
```

для браузера Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос так:

```
background:url("../image/strelka.png") no-repeat 97.5% 50% transparent;
 -webkit-background-size:12%;
 -moz-background-size:12%;
 -o-background-size:12%;
 background-size:12%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте!

```
    background: url("../image/strelka.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
```

Comment: Вот http://jsfiddle.net/xkcz4789/ , как смог

Comment: @Sergey, Конкретный скажите чем проблема?! Вроде все номально работает на виндовс.

Comment: Стрелка, которая между блоками растянута на весь задний фон http://prntscr.com/74rx81. А нужно, что бы было так http://prntscr.com/74ry8n